# Issues with static variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript, static, global

I am having some issue with a static variable in php. I am calling a php function from another JS function, and the static variable isn't increasing. Shouldn't it be?

Here's something like what I'm trying to do(just very simplified);

```
<?php
    function someFunc() {
        static $y = 0;
        ++$y;
        return $y;
    }
?>
<script>
    function someFunc() {
        var x = 0;
        while (++x<=31) {
            <?php echo someFunc(); ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issue with this code is, the `<?php echo someFunc(); ?>` just returns '1'. Every time it loops as well.
Can somebody explain why this is happening and if there is a workaround.

Comment: Because that's what JavaScript will have as a variable at the load time. JavaScript can't access the PHP `someFunc`, because the first is a client side language (which runs on the user's machine) and the latter is a server side (which runs on the server).

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server side script which runs and finishes long before the javascript even loads into the users browser.

This means that that PHP function will run once as the server sends the page to the client. Look at the source code client side. It looks like this:

```
<script>
     function someFunc() {
         var x = 0;
         while (++x<=31) {
             1
         }
     }
</script>
```

You cannot intermix javascript and PHP in the way that you are trying to. For something this simple, you would use all PHP if you need server side resources, or all javascript if not. If you need server side resources AFTER the page has finished loading, you would want to research AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Code bellow is interpreted as plain text and is not executed.

```
<script>
    function someFunc() {
        var x = 0;
        while (++x<=31) {
            <?php echo someFunc(); ?>  // EXCEPT FOR THIS LINE
        }
    }
</script>
```

While `<?php echo someFunc(); ?>` gets executed once and returns 1.

PHP is executed serverside - JavaScript clienside.

You effectively generating following **text** and passing to browser:

```
<script>
    function someFunc() {
        var x = 0;
        while (++x<=31) {
            1
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript isnt going to call your php function, he tow are not connected. You are simply echoing the return for the php `someFunc()` at the time the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

So php and js do not execute at the same time, php is executed on the server and sent to the browser, which then executes the js.

Because of this, what is being sent to the browser is:

```
<script>
    function someFunc() {
        var x = 0;
        while (++x<=31) {
            1
        }
    }
</script>
```

The php someFunc() one gets run once because js inst looping at this time.

Comment: Guess I'll try some AJAX then...because I do need them to mix like this...Hmmm...

Thanks though guys! You were lots of help. :D

Comment: @Cweener: dont thank him.. select his answer and give him some points ;-)